# Django overwrite validate MultipleChoiceField and remove queryset required

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

i'm tring to make a custom MultipleChoiceField but i have 2 problems

1st seems i can't overwrite validate function... when i try it print("i'm here") never come in my console even when that field triggers invalid_choice error

```
class OdsTaggerlMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.tag
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OdsTaggerlMultipleChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.to_field_name="tag"
        self.widget.attrs['class'] = 'odstagger'
    
    def validate(self, value):
        #azione cattiva valida la qualunque
        if self.required and len(value) < 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'], code='required')
        print("i'm here")
```

2nd problem is about queryset it's required to use that field, but i think resolving 1ts problem i can just use a empty choices list

```
tags = OdsTaggerlMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all())
```

do you know how resolve that?

Comment: Why do you even need to do that? The field [already](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0250340e372f652c4f276e6874d452d683c94dfe/django/forms/models.py#L1326) checks that... Also `validate` is never called for a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

Comment: I want replace validate function bcz I need remove Invalid_choice error... With a js I add some new options in <select> ...